# Is it possible to layer lists in a board two dimensionally

Tags: trello, list

I have a number of short lists on a board, and I'd prefer to stack them up using the entire canvas, rather than have them scroll off to the right. Is it possible (or will it be possible) to do that ? right now, whenever I drag a board, it goes back to its original spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen automatically if you make your browser window narrow enough, or if you access Trello from a mobile browser, but there is no manual way to induce this behavior.